# Where I can find an already done Facebook JSON reader made in PHP?

Tags: php, json, facebook

Where I can find an already done Facebook JSON reader made in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook [PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) will allow you to make Facebook calls (Graph and REST) and will decode the json response for you, distinguishing if the response is an error or not.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP itself.

[`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode)

Comment: I know the existance of json_decode().
But I want to find something already done that can show the flow of facebook in PHP.
So I don't have to use json_decode() and parse all the facebook json.

Comment: It's not hard at all to parse.

Comment: @cee this question is off-topic because it is seeking a resource / software.

Comment: @mickmackusa SO policies were slightly different in 2011.

Comment: That's okay.  It is never too late to curate old content and bring it to the current standards.  Just needs one more close vote.